# Are CoffeeScript servers not as reliable as Node.js servers?

Tags: javascript, web-services, node.js, heroku, coffeescript

I took the code for my Node.js server and converted it to CoffeeScript, then I tried it on Heroku. It crashes when it receives a long JSON string, whereas the original version handles it without any problem. Is this normal?

Comment: Coffeescript compiles down to Javascript, so you can easily check the resulting code yourself.

Comment: Coffeescript is javascript. I'd venture a guess that your port has an error.

Comment: It's not the port, because I can see on the server that it's receiving data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say writing in CoffeeScript is (potentially) *much* more reliable than writing pure JavaScript.

From [CoffeeScript's documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3azip%20%3D%20lottery.drawWinner%3F%28%29.address%3F.zipcode%0A):

**CoffeeScript:**

```
zip = lottery.drawWinner?().address?.zipcode
```

**Generated JavaScript:**

```
var zip, _ref;

zip = typeof lottery.drawWinner === "function" ? 
      (_ref = lottery.drawWinner().address) != null ? 
      _ref.zipcode : void 0 : void 0;
```

I don't know about you, but I usually forget to check the type against `function`, or otherwise am too lazy to consider `null` or `undefined`. Besides, it makes JavaScript code much uglier and harder to read and maintain.

It's certainly a bug in you poring your app. Make sure you understand and exploit what `do(i){}`, `for key, value of hash`, `for item,index in array`. Explicitly `return` at the end of functions, and double check variable scopes. I'm sure you'll find that it was a bug in your port (as did I, a few weeks back).